# What is the BKM to deploy OSGI bundles with new changes?

Tags: java, jboss, osgi, versioning

We have been using OSGI with Jboss 7.0.1 and have multiple bundles supporting our application. We are trying to adapt the versioning strategy of Major.Minor.Micro for Interface + Service Implementation + Consumer based model, but it seems our strategy might not be right.

When we bump up the minor version for api and service the consumer is unable to use the new service without having to do package refresh.

Below is the usecase.

Package **com.helloworld.api** is exported with version 1.0.0  from bundle  **Helloworld API** (interface bundle)

```
public interface IHelloService {
    public void sayHello(String abc);
}
```

Menifest File for  **Helloworld API**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Helloworld API
Bundle-SymbolicName: exp1.com.helloworld.api
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.helloworld.internal.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: ABC
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: com.helloworld.api;version="1.0.0"
```

Implemented by  **HelloServiceImpl** from bundle **Helloworldservice**

```
public class HelloServiceImpl implements IHelloService {

@Override
  public void sayHello(String abc) {
      System.out.println(" \n\n ~~~~~~~~~ "+abc+" ~~~~~~~~~  " + "   \n\n");
  }
}
```

Menifest File for **Helloworldservice**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Helloworldservice
Bundle-SymbolicName: exp1.com.helloworld.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.helloworldservice.internal.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: ABC
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.helloworld.api;version="1.0.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath:
```

Consumed by Consumer from bundle **Consumer Service** (Using service tracker or Google Guice approach). It keeps on calling sayHello in loop.

```
HelloWorldServiceProxy.getInstance().getHelloWorldService().sayHello("abc  " + "Index" + i);
```

Menifest File for **Consumer Service**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Consumer Service
Bundle-SymbolicName: exp1.com.consumer
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.consumer.internal.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.helloworld.api;version="1.0.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.0"
```

After that we make the modification to api and add new method. This results into bumping up the minor version to 1.1.0. To support this we implement the new method in service but expect the consumer to be untouched.

package **com.helloworld.api** is exported with version 1.1.0  from bundle  **Helloworld API**

```
public interface IHelloService {
   public void sayHello(String abc);
   public void sayHello(String abc, String def, int a);
}
```

Menifest File for  **Helloworld API**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Helloworld API
Bundle-SymbolicName: exp1.com.helloworld.api
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.helloworld.internal.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: ABC
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: helloworld.api;version="1.1.0"
```

Implemented by **HelloServiceImpl** from bundle **Helloworldservice**

```
public class HelloServiceImpl implements IHelloService {
  @Override
  public void sayHello(String abc) {
    System.out.println(" \n\n ~~~~~~~~~ "+abc+" ~~~~~~~~~  " + "   \n\n");
  }
  @Override
  public void sayHelloNew(String abc, String def, int a) {
    System.out.println(" \n\n ~~~~~~~~~ "+abc+" NEW METHOD ### WITH CHANGE ### ~~~~~~~~~  " + abc +"  " + def +"   \n\n");
  }
}
```

Menifest File

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Helloworldservice
Bundle-SymbolicName: exp1.com.helloworld.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.helloworldservice.internal.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: ABC
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.helloworld.api;version="1.1.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ClassPath:
```

However, now when we deploy HelloWorld Api and HelloWorld Service bundles, the consumer bundle is unable to start using the new service exported with package 1.1.0. We are having to refresh the consumer bundle in order to make it work.

Are we doing something wrong here ?

So far we have been deploying new bundles without any version (defaults to 0.0.0). Deploying new bundles with same package revision works fine for micro changes but any method signature change or new method usage results into NoSuchMethod exception until we perform the global package refresh from Jboss. That is the reason we decided to use Jboss version strategy.

Comment: What is the meaning of BKM?

Comment: Best Known Method :)

Answer (score 0):

After you install/update new bundles you should ALWAYS refresh. No exceptions. The only reason that refresh is not integrated with update/install is that you can now install/update multiple bundles before you refresh.

I am also a bit puzzled about your examples. You talk about semantic versioning but your imports are from [1.3.0,∞), so there is no semantic version in play? (It also helps to remove unnecessary information like most of the headers.)

So what is the best practice?

First, a service is defined by a *package*. For this service you can have two types of interfaces: interfaces implemented by the *consumers* and interfaces by the *providers*. A consumer interface is only changed in a non-backward compatible when for a major release bump. A provider interface is broken on a minor release bump. (major.minor.micro) OSGi supports the @ConsumerType (default) and @ProviderType annotations for an interface.

If you use bnd then you automatically get an import range. I.e. if your `IHello` (better not append it with service) starts at 1.0:

```
 IHello.java:
 package com.example.hello;

 public interface IHello {
   void sayHell();
 }

 @Version("1.0.0")
 package-info.java:

 import org.osgi.annotation.versioning.Version;
```

Since the default case this is a @ConsumerType we will get the following import:

```
 Import-Package: com.example.hello;version='[1.0,2)'
```

However, the IHello interface likely represents a provider. So we should annotate it with the @ProviderType:

```
 IHello.java:
 package com.example.hello;

 import org.osgi.annotation.versioning.ProviderType;

 @ProviderType
 public interface IHello {
   void sayHell();
 }
```

If you now write a provider that implements the IHello service bnd will detect the version of the com.example.hello package. Since it sees that you implement it, it will write out the following import:

```
 Import-Package: com.example.hello;version='[1.0,1.1)'
```

If we had written a client of the IHello service our import would have been [1.0,2).

If we now add a method to IHello we should bump the version to 1.1 since IHello was a @ProviderType. (If it had been a @ConsumerType we would have been forced to bump it to 2.0)

```
 package-info.java:
 @Version("1.1.0")
 package-info.java:

 import org.osgi.annotation.versioning.Version;

 IHello.java:
 package com.example.hello;

 import org.osgi.annotation.versioning.ProviderType;

 @ProviderType
 public interface IHello {
   void sayHell();
   void sayHello(String s);
 }
```

We now effectively broke the provider of the IHello service, which is exactly what we want! This will prevent calling a 1.1 service that is backed by an implementation that was compiled against 1.0.

Summary:

- refresh is mandatory after install/update.
- Used bnd

Comment: Hi Kriens, Thanks a lot for your reply.  I wanted to narrow down the focus to single modification. Hence to avoid complexity used the versions like this. I have not tried providerType and consumerType interface before, I will give it a try. Also we did do package refresh on API and API.Service after the minor version bump but the consumer did not pick up the new service until it was refreshed as well. Do you also recommend to do package refresh on consumer even if it is not changed at all ? Won't it cause interruption in consumer ?

Comment: So basically when api export and service import both move to 1.1.0 from 1.0.0 , why do we have to do package refresh on consumer that was happily using 1.0.0 ? The new version is compatible with consumer, shouldn't it be able to use it without having to do package refresh on consumer (given we do perform package refresh on newly deployed api and service)?

Comment: Theoretically you can minimize the effect of the refresh. And actually, you can selectively refresh only the bundles you want by specifying them in the refresh call (The framework automatically adds any dependents.) However, I've never been able to understand why you want to trade a tiny bit of time to restart for a rather large amount of complexity. You can't depend on the behavior since there are always cases where you need to restart. So I would minimize complexity and use one path instead of creating lots of possible constellations in your code.